# sed delete number between single quotes

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file like:

```
35.26660,129.0373,'207636');
35.26667,129.0375,'207636');
35.55555,129.0377,'207636');
```

I want to delete last number between single quotes and the corresponding comma. I want the result to be like:

```
35.26660,129.0373);
35.26667,129.0375);
35.55555,129.0377);
```

I tried to use sed, but I made a mistake and I cannot see what is the problem.
If I use command:

```
sed "s/'//g"
```

Then I delete only the quotes

If I use command:

```
sed "s/[0-9]//g"
```

Then I delete only number between single quotes.

**Update #1:**

Sorry, in few lines I have a more data like:

```
'abc', '123' 35.26660,129.0373,'207636');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
sed "s/,'[^']*')/)/"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak "s/,'[^']*'//" file
```

It gives:

```
35.26660,129.0373);
35.26667,129.0375);
35.55555,129.0377);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F\' '{$2="";sub(/, +/,"")}1' file
35.26660,129.0373);
35.26667,129.0375);
35.55555,129.0377);
```